# NodeJS/Javascript select a object starting with #?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my response:

```
{ artist:
   { '#text': 'Sam Smith',
     mbid: '5a85c140-dcf9-4dd2-b2c8-aff0471549f3' },
  song: 'Stay with Me',
  from:
   { '#text': 'In the Lonely Hour',
     mbid: 'f43d20c0-2fa5-4bc2-9c42-c677e346e768' } }
```

Now I want to select to artist name, ( "#text" ) but how to select a property starting with #?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation), like this

```
console.log(data.artist['#text'])
```